# Voice over continues to read previous page even when page is turned

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, mac-catalyst

We have a reader app similar to apple books. We are facing following accessibility issue on mac catalyst version of the app:

When the content on the page is read out by voice over and we turn the page using keyboard arrow keys, even though the page gets turned and the focus also goes to the next page, the voice over continues to read the previous page.

Can you please suggest what needs to be done and how it is fixed in apple books mac app.

I tried following things but none of them worked:

Post `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` when page is turned. This didn’t work and the announcement does not interrupts it, it just continues to read the previous page. Though the announcement string gets appended in the end and VO speaks when it is done with reading. (we don't have `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement` overridden, i even tried to set it to false explicitly as well)
Post `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` or `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` or `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` when page is turned.
I know that apple books also has similar issue till macOS Monterey but it is fixed in macOS Ventura but for us this issue is still in macOS ventura.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Post the `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` notification, and pass along the your new view that should be focussed-on by the accessibility system.

[See documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityscreenchangednotification?language=objc). It states

> Post this notification using the [`UIAccessibilityPostNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityscreenchangednotification?language=objc#:%7E:text=UIAccessibilityPostNotification) function. Optionally, include a parameter that contains the accessibility element for VoiceOver to move to after processing the notification.

You can use this function like so:

`UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: viewToBeFocussed)`

where `viewToBeFocussed` is the view that contains the text to be read by the accessibility system.